# Find character pattern using regex

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, match, string-matching

I am trying to find all occurrences of a special character `/` surrounded by either letters or numbers.

After many tries, I have come up with the following Regex that almost does what I need:

```
(?![a-z0-9])\/(?=[a-z0-9])
```

This works fine for these examples:

```
aa/aa
123/123
aa/123
```

However, it fails if there are two forward slashes together:

```
http://regexr.com/
```

In this case, it matches the second forward slash after `http` which I do not want.

How can I modify this Regex to meet my needs?

**EDIT:** I do **not** want to a match when two forward slashes are together.  I only want to match if a single forward slash is surrounded by alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Then you want the result to be `http://regexr.com/` not detected as a match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would need a positive lookbehind group, like so:

```
(?<=[a-z0-9])+\/{1}(?=[a-z0-9]+)
```

however, according to http://regexr.com/ it is not supported in javascript.

Works fine in e.g. python [http://pythex.org/](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3C%3D%5Ba-z0-9%5D)%2B%5C%2F(%3F%3D%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B)&test_string=rary%2C%20or%20watch%20the%20video%20Tutorial.%0Asdf%2F556%20fdfg%2Fw45%0Aaa%2Faa%0A123%2F123%0Aaa%2F123%0ASample%20text%20for%20testing%3A%0Aabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%20ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%0A0123456789%20_%2B-.%2C!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()%3B%5C%2F%7C%3C%3E%22%27%0A12345%20-98.7%203.141%20.6180%209%2C000%20%2B42%0A555.123.4567%09%2B1-(800)-555-2468%0Afoo%40demo.net%09bar.ba%40test.co.uk%0Awww.demo.com%09http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.co.uk%2F%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fregexr.com%2Ffoo.html%3Fq%3Dbar&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0%20pythex.org)

Answer (score 2):

Easy!

```
(?![a-z0-9])\/+(?=[a-z0-9])
```

You should have put `+` for 1 on more occurrence of a character. So you should have written `\/+` instead of just `\/`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(!?[a-z0-9])\/(?=[a-z0-9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[a-z0-9](\/)[a-z0-9]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hM0wU4/1)

**Explanation:**
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)